# Dependency Injection Problems

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, solid-principles

I've got into dependency inversion principle and inversion of control just recently, and from what I currently know(correct me if I'm wrong) is that DIP states that

> high level module/class should not be dependent upon the low-level module/class
>
> both high and low-level module should not depend on details(not sure what this one means???), but abstractions(interfaces)

but when I was writing a simple program to implement this principle, i ran into a problem(will explain it later)

My program consist of an Inventory and Player class that implements "ICharacterable"

```
      class Player : ICharacterable {

    private int _health = 100;

    public int Health{

        get{
            return _health;
        }

    }

    public int HealthIncrease(int health){
        //increase health
        return _health + health;

    }


}

class Inventory{

    ICharacterable player = null;

    //constructor injection
    public Inventory(ICharacterable player) {

        this.player = player;

    }

    //increase player health
    public void UseHealthPotion(int health) {

        player.HealthIncrease(health);

    }

}

class Program{
static void Main(string[] args) {

    Player john = new Player();
    Inventory inv = new Inventory(john);

    inv.UseHealthPotion(30);
    Console.WriteLine(john.Health);
     
}

}
 
 //interface
public interface ICharacterable {

    int HealthIncrease(int health);

}
```

the problem is, the Console returns 100 instead of 130. I figure that the problem was caused due to the fact that I declared was injecting a ICharacterable type instead of Player(but that would violate the DIP), is there anyway I could do this? Thanks

Comment: Side not about the model, "Inventory HAS-A Player" sounds strange. And who drinks potions, players or inventories?

Comment: Why does `HealthIncrease` return anything? I would either mutate state (i.e. increase the player's health field) or perform and return a sum, I would not do both, that is a side effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get bad result, because your method only returns result of the addition and not change a state of the object. Everything else is correct. Change it to:

```
public int HealthIncrease(int health){
    //increase health
    _health += health;
    return _health;
}
```

You should only consider small replacement, in my opinion *Player* should contains *Inventory*, rather than vice versa. Then you will follow OOP design patterns and your code will be much better.

> high level module/class should not be dependent upon the low-level
>   module/class

In this case *Player* = high-level class and *Inventory* = low-level class

> both high and low-level module should not depend on details(not sure what this one means???), but abstractions(interfaces)

Quick explanation:

**Abstractions** = interface or abstract class. Quite easy to understand, it's your *ICharactable* interface.

**Details** = implementation. It's your *Inventory* class. What makes your code compatible with this principle.

Comment: Hey, could you please elaborate on "You should only consider small replacement, in my opinion Player should contains Inventory. Then you will follow OOP design patterns and your code will be much better." 
I was told that every class should only have one responsiblity, and how will i benefit from it? thanks

Comment: @Lef that's true, it don't change this behaviour. I mean - Player should have Inventory as dependency, rather than vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a dependency injection problem, you just have a bug in the code here:

```
   public int HealthIncrease(int health){
        //increase health
        return _health += health;

    }
```